# Dual booted ubuntu cannot be opened. It is lost?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8

I've dual-booted my mother's laptop with windows and ubuntu 16.04 during the summer.  Now she can't seem to even get into ubuntu.  It's like disappeared.  She has no grub menu - where you can select which OS system you want to enter - and her F2 boot menu doesn't work either.  The boot menu shows ubuntu, but when she selects it, the laptop sill goes to windows.  She did recently do an update with windows, and since then, she can't get into ubuntu.
Please help!!  Thanks in advance.  P

Comment: It sounds almost like you've been hit by the notorious `Windows 10 Anniversary Update` bug. Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD and take a screenshot of your /dev/sda disk, and edit that screenshot into your question for me to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Install EasyBCD on windows and add new Linux entry point.
make sure to select the correct partition where u installed the ubuntu bootloader when adding the entry point.
now go to boot menu option there now should be 2 operating systems listed (windows and ubuntu) select save settings and restart ur PC.

Comment: What if the user doesn't know how to determine the correct partition for the "Linux entry point"? You need to explain how the user should do this. What if the Ubuntu partition has been wiped clean? Etc. User also indicates that their F2 boot menu doesn't work. You need to ask some more questions via comments before composing an answer.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean but do not yest have enough privilege to comment on other's posts .
And as for the the ubuntu partition being wiped...I think thats highly unlikely because  ,even thought i am a noob , I have observed that windows(usually) does not want anything to do with ext4 partitions.....they are basically inaccessible(yes the can be formated via third party apps like mini partition tools etc....).

**(CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT)**

Comment: And as for identifying the correct bootloader location....If the user had selected a different partition than the default one for bootloader then I  think its safe to assume the user knew what he was doing and would  remember it or at least would be able to recall it.
If the has left it to be the default one then it should be same partition where the windows bootloader is installed which is is (_correct me if I m wrong_)the small "system reserved" partition. (**continued in next comment**)

Comment: The partition number (like sda1 or sda2 etc) can be easily identified using some third party apps like **Mini Partition Tool** or **EaseUS Partition Manager**

Comment: The notorious `Microsoft Windows 10 Anniversary Update` has a habit of wiping out Ubuntu EXT4 partitions. That's why I mentioned about missing partitions. In general, your answer needs to not be too general, and to provide a tangible solution, and not make any assumptions about the users level of expertise.